# In RubyMine, how to preview a file's contents by selecting it like in Sublime Text?

Tags: rubymine

I'm new to RubyMine 7 on Mac.
I used to use Sublime Text 3 and I love RubyMine so far except its lack of file previewing.

In Sublime Text, when clicking a file in the sidebar (file explorer), the selected file content shows in an editor tab for temporary viewing.
If I select another file, then the same tab changes to the content of the newly selected file.

I've been searching for this preference setting in RubyMine, or in a plugin, but I've had no luck.

A similar feature is "Autoscroll to source" but this feature opens files rather than previewing them.

If anyone knows how to do Sublime Text-like file content previewing in RubyMine, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open temporary/preview tab in intellij Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063526/how-to-open-temporary-preview-tab-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Good news: this is possible now! The newer question I linked has an answer that explains how to activate the "preview tab" feature

Answer (score 0):

[RubyMine doesn't have a feature exactly like Sublime Text file previewing.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999985-option-for-preview-selected-file-)

The Quick Definition action can sometimes meet the same need. When invoked on a file, it opens a popup with the file's contents. You can invoke it on a file in the Project or Find pane and probably other panes, dialogs, popups, etc. that list files. (You can also invoke it in an editor on an identifier such as a class, module, or variable; it will show the code that defines the identifier.) Invoke Quick Definition with ⌥-space or ⌘Y in the Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap; use ^⇧I on Windows or check Preferences → Keymap for other keymaps, or use ⇧⌘A qd ⏎. Hit Escape or click outside the popup to close it.

When you invoke Quick Definition on a file in the Project pane and navigate to other files in that pane (with down and up arrows to move between files, and right and left arrows or Enter to open and close directories), the Quick Definition popup will stay open and update to the currently selected file, which is relatively close to Sublime Text file previewing. You can also hit Enter to open a file, F4 to open a file and move focus to the editor, edit the file, ⌘1 to jump back to the Project pane, etc., all with the Quick Definition popup still open, until you choose to close it.

If that isn't close enough, there are two feature requests for Sublime Text-like file previewing in JetBrains IDEs which you can vote for:

- [Preview currently selected file in project window](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124569)
- [File Preview features from Sublime](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130918)