# How to open temporary/preview tab in intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-idea-2016

I like VS Code and sublime editor and in particular their default behaviour of preview the file. When you single click on a file from file explorer pan, it would open it in a temporary tab, unless a change is made in the file or opened with a double click on file, which opens it on persist tab.

Recently I've to use IntelliJ IDEA in a project and so far I like it this particular functionality is holding me up to adopt it completely. How to achieve this temporary/preview tab behaviour in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find some workarounds in the open request, or just follow it for updates:

- [IDEA-130918](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130918) File Preview features from Sublime

### Update

This is now a feature in version 2020.3+

[image: 'Enable preview tab' checkbox in Settings -> Editor -> General -> Editor Tabs section]

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder